# If $\inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}=-\infty$, why $\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=-\infty ?$

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that:

If $(x_n)_n$ is a subadditive sequence (i.e. $x_{{n+m}}\leq x_{n}+x_{m}$ for all $n,m$). Then, $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ exists (may be $-\infty$).

I see a proof of the above result and I understand the following case: If $ \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}> -\infty$ then  $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ exists and $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}\tfrac{x_n}{n}.
$$

**This is the proof:**

[image]

> My problem  is:  if $ \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}= -\infty$ why $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=-\infty ?
> $$

Comment: For the same reason if the limit is finite.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If the limit exists must equal the $\inf$. Are you trying to prove that if the $\inf$ is $-\infty$ then the limit exists? Because that it not clear from the above.

Comment: @copper.hat I mean $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}\tfrac{x_n}{n}.$$

Comment: I only understand the proof of the fact: if $ \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}> -\infty$ then $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ exists and $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}^*}\tfrac{x_n}{n}.
$$ My problem  is:  if $ \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}= -\infty$ why $$\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}=-\infty.
$$

Comment: @Schüler: That is not clear from your question.

Comment: @copper.hat I edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original Answer**: Since $\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} n^{-1}x_n=-\infty$, there exists a sequence $n_j\to\infty$ such that $\frac1{n_j}x_{n_j}<-j$.  Taking $j\to\infty$ gives $\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac1{n_j}x_{n_j}=-\infty$.  Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1nx_n$ exists (in the extended reals)
$$
-\infty=\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac{x_{n_j}}{n_j}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}
$$
where the final equality follows from $\frac1{n_j}x_{n_j}$ being a subsequence of $\frac1nx_n$.

---

**Modifed Anaswer**: To prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n x_n$ exists, for every $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n>m>0$ we get $n=mq+r$, some $0\leq r<n$, so subadditivity gives
$$
a_n\leq qa_m+a_r
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}\leq \frac{q}{mq+r} a_m+\frac1{mq+r} a_r.
$$
Taking limit superior as $n\to\infty$ gives
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n \leq\limsup_{q\to\infty}\max_{r=0,1,\dots,m-1}\left[\frac{q}{mq+r} a_m+\frac1{mq+r} a_r\right]=\frac{a_m}m
$$
So we can take inf over $m$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n
\leq\inf_m\frac{a_m}m
$$
and so in this case we conclude $\limsup_n \frac1n a_n=-\infty$ and so also $\liminf_n\frac1n a_n=-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think in you proof, you have assumed that one has already proved that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1nx_n$ exists.

Comment: Yes.  Didn't you say you have a proof of that?

Comment: No need to split the cases.  See [this answer to a previous SE question](/a/719981).

Comment: Please in your answer why if $ \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \frac{x_n}{n}= -\infty$ then $\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ exists ?

Comment: See modified answer.  It is the same proof as in the above link.

Comment: The case $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ can be equal to $-\infty$ can be illustrate with the example $x_n=-n^2$. Please why $\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\tfrac{x_n}{n}$ cannot be equal to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: Subadditivity gives $x_n\leq nx_1$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n/n$ cannot be $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the link why it does not split two cases?

Comment: Because there is no need to split into two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x_{n+1} \le x_n + x_1$ and so $x_n \le n x_1$ from which we get
${x_n \over n} \le x_1$.

Then ${x_{m+n} \over m+n} \le {x_n \over n} {n \over m+n} + {x_m \over m} {m \over m+n} \le {x_n \over n} + x_1$.

Suppose $\inf_n {x_n \over n} = -\infty$, then $\lim_k {x_{n_k} \over n_k} = -\infty$ for some subsequence.

Choose $L$, and pick $k$ such that ${x_{n_k} \over n_k} < L-x_1 $. Then for $n > n_k$ we have
${x_n \over n} = {x_{n_k+(n-n_k)} \over n_k+(n-n_k) } \le {x_{n_k} \over n_k}+x_1 < L$.

Comment: Is this proof correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719981 because it does not split two cases?

Comment: It looks fine, why do you ask?

Comment: Thank you because I find it more easy than the one that I found.